# "pretty_print" does not work well for xml shown in python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a string object with xml content. In python, I used etree to pretty print it. It works well in python 2.x, but fails to be shown in python 3.x.

```
from lxml import etree
print etree.tostring(etree.fromstring(patternXML), pretty_print=True)
```

I expect the xml is shown well as line breaks, but the actual output is bytes type and "\n" is shown instead of line break.

Answer (score 4):

It has been resolved by changing "tostring" to "tounicode" as below.

```
print etree.tounicode(etree.fromstring(patternXML), pretty_print=True)
```